# Firebase Dynamic Link linkStats

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

linkStats returns an empty JSON object. How do you retrieve the stats for a shortlink created through Firebase? Is this supported?

https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/:link/linkStats?durationDays=2

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't input FDL to <:link> and Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN> to the header.

Please check the following guides.
[View Dynamic Links Analytics Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics#rest_api)
[API Authorization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics#api_authorization)